# How can i connect to my azure windows machine after disconnect the internet from it?

Tags: azure

I disconnected the internet from the VM. I can not connect to my VM. I tried to reset remote access and change password.

Can any body help me access my windows machine

Comment: I think you need to change the nic internal IP address, it will reconfigure the nic (i think in fact it will create a new nic in the vm)

Answer (score 0):

If there is another VM in the subnet, try to rdp from that machine using private IP.